# Typescript errors out when enums are present inside an Immutable record

Tags: typescript, immutable.js

```
import { Record } from 'immutable'

export enum PriceRelationType {
  nForX,
  nForPriceOfX
}

export interface PriceRelation {
  type: PriceRelationType
  quantity: number
  price: number
}

export interface ProductType {
  id: string
  name: string
  image: string
  description: string
  price: {
    relations: PriceRelation[]
    scale: number
  }
}

export const ProductRecord: Record.Factory<ProductType> = Record({
  id: '',
  name: '',
  image: '',
  description: '',
  price: {
    relations: [{ quantity: 0, price: 0, type: PriceRelationType.nForX }],
    scale: 0
  }
})
```

For the given block of code, Typescript refuses to compile it by giving the following error

```
Types of property 'price' are incompatible.
            Type '{ relations: PriceRelation[]; scale: number; } | undefined' is not assignable to type '{ relations: { quantity: number; price: number; type: PriceRelationType.nForX; }[]; scale: number; } | undefined'.
              Type '{ relations: PriceRelation[]; scale: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ relations: { quantity: number; price: number; type: PriceRelationType.nForX; }[]; scale: number; }'.
```

It seems that there is something wrong with the enum value as removing it fixes the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that explicitly typing the relations array will solve this issue, eg:

```
export const ProductRecord: Record.Factory<ProductType> = Record({
  id: '',
  name: '',
  image: '',
  description: '',
  price: {
    relations: <PriceRelation[]>[ <PriceRelation>{ quantity: 0, price: 0, type: PriceRelationType.nForX }],
    scale: 0
  }
})
```

Comment: Why, though? It definitely seems like the compiler has enough info to infer this.

Comment: Think of it more about how you can treat that object after you instantiate it. With a plain JS object like you were using (aka an `any` type), you're free to mutate it as much as you want -- you can add and delete properties at will. Because you're explicitly telling TypeScript that your `price.relations` array must contain only `PriceRelation` objects, the objects that you fill that array with must be explicitly typed as well. Unfortunately, TypeScript doesn't automatically perform nested type inference like that -- even though the object shapes are similar.

Comment: Or put in other words: The output type of `Record(template)` is defined by `template`. When the compiler checks both sides, it rightfully detects that `any` cannot be cast to `PriceRelation`. The ability to infer from any to a specific type would make TS obsolete.